# User input to Concept N

Tags: sony, sony-future-lab-n

I am trying to create a simple reminder segment, after looking related API, I didn't found API related to voice/text input or something like (or just I search in wrong way), my goal is easy, let segment receive user sentences like 'remind me buying egg','remind me phone back later'.

I know I can achieve it by defining these in LaunchRules.json but it would become complex if I want provide more use case. If is possible to let user input/recognize some sentence , or just recording a 10-sec voice memo is possible in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you will only be able to create voice commands in LaunchRules.json for now. Also keep in mind that every voice command you create will begin with "start" or "check" for the user. For instance if you create a launch rule of "reminder to buy eggs" the user will access this by either "start reminder to buy eggs" or "check reminder to buy eggs"